# How do I track referrals from installations on the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an app in the chrome web store and I want to track what promotion drove each user who installed the application. For instance, did this user see my blog post and click through to the store from there or was it my facebook page?

I'd like to do this on a per user basis and not an aggregate basis so I have the option to adjust the user experience/messaging based on where the user came from.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: So far I've tried to set a cookie and then read it from the app to determine the source but I can't do that from places like Facebook.

Comment: I highly doubt it's possible.

Comment: @Xan - Have you tried it before? Can you shed some light on why you don't think it's possible?

Comment: @PCChris i am looking for a similar data for my chrome extension. Are you following the cookies method or did you find any other alternate ? Thanks